# mysql doesn't take accents into account validating uniqueness of index key

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation, unique-key

I have a table with just a single field named "tag", which is a varchar(250)

the field is defined with collation 'latin1_spanish_ci', because I'm planning to save words in spanish...

the problem is that the following query

```
select * from test where tag = 'unó'
```

gives me exactly the same result as

```
select * from test where tag = 'uno'
```

that is, for mysql, 'uno' = 'unó'... and 'unò', and 'unö'... etc...

this field is supossed to have a unique key...

I tried with others collations, all the "bin" collations seem to work, and also latin1_general_ci too...

I'd just like to know if this would be the appropiate collation to choose for every field in the database, or if I might face any trouble choosing it... take into account that I'm planing to store spanish data in that db...

saludos

sas

ps: anyway, it seems really odd that in a spanish collation accents could be considered meaningless...

--

edit: I did a couple of tests, I entered data with á Á é É ñ Ñ, etc, and it seems like mysql can really handle them ok...

Answer (score 2):

You could use `latin1_general_ci` as your default database/table/column collation and specify `latin1_spanish_ci` on a per-select basis where needed:

```
select * from test order by tag collate latin1_spanish_ci;
select * from test where tag = 'uno' collate latin1_spanish_ci;
```

Because 'o', 'ó' etc. are considered equal in `latin1_spanish_ci`, the latter statement returns multiple results if the table contains e.g. 'uno', 'unó' and 'unò'.

Answer (score 1):

The collation is not used to define in which language is the data in the column. It is used to define how different letters or multiple letters/codepoints must be defined as the same for comparisons (ordering and equality).

The `ci` suffix of `latin1_spanish_ci` means *case insensitive*.

If you want to be able to distinguish any accentuated letter and any case, the collation named after a language name are not appropriate. Use instead the collations with the `_bin` suffix.

You can also [attach a specific collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-collation.html) to a value to force the use of a specific collation over the collation of the column:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE tag = ('uno' COLLATE latin1_bin);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UTF-8 collation to differentiate the value.

Answer (score 0):

this is a quick fix to this issue.

'unó' should be saved as 'un`&#243;`' on your database.

Then your search should look like

SELECT * from database where field = 'un`&#243;`'

Using the UNICODE HTML ENTITY is the key https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00F3 ... Cheers !